# How can I start a server side application automatically?

Tags: web-applications, server-side, chatbot

I want to develop a chatbot that sometimes sends messages on its own. That means it have to become active by itself. How can I do this?

Comment: Why does it need to run on a webserver - it could just be a standalone application ? you could set it up using windows scheduled or crontab ...

Comment: I never heard of crontab. It should run on a normal webserver. Is this possible by your idea?

Comment: Agreed, you don't need a server to do this.  You can run it as a Windows App, a Windows Service, a cronjob in unix/linux, etc., etc.

Comment: I dont need a server? I dont have a running computer during my holidays!

Comment: I'm pretty sure your Facebook friends don't want to talk to a robot.

Comment: Of course, this was just an example. What's the best way for writing such a robot?

Comment: @ManseUK: crontab with cronjobs are the needed answer. Write in in a answer if you want to get the "accepted answer". (and maybe vote post up...)

Comment: @sharethis done .. glad I could be of help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best method is to create a standalone application (in whatever language you choose) then create a crontab / windows scheduler entry to run the application. The application doesnt need to run in a browser to connect to a web based application.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a server for this. Maybe you could use you experience with JavaScript to write a browser extension (for example for Chrome: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/index.html). A browser extension will have direct access to the Facebook page in your browser and it will make your life much easier to communicate this way with the Facebook server.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But there is no Browser when I am on the beach enjoying holidays.

Comment: Well, you need to have a computer running regardsless of whether you run your code in a web server or in a browser. If you must use a web server, you should have a look at the Facebook chat API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/. The sample code on that page is PHP.

Comment: Ok, but my first step is to get the code running automatically. For that I dont need the Facebook API. But how can I write a self running program on a server? Is it possible with C++ or C# for example? How do I have to configure the server for that? (It's not my own hardware server, I only pay it from a hoster -> FTP, PHP, ...)

Comment: A PHP script runs each time a request is send to the web server, so if you insist on using PHP to interface with Facebook, you need to invoke your script from time to time using for instance a cron job or another computer that sends requests with some interval. If you want to hack something up in PHP using the Facebook API, you will have a lot of work ahead of you.